# What is the best method for auditing in Asp.net SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql

I was searching the best way for auditing and logging, i found many ways for auditing 
but just need confirmation which one is best method for auditing?

Comment: which options have you considered so far?

Comment: any link , suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Need more info. Are you speaking of auditing based on application logic? Are you speaking of error logging or common, step by step  application logging?

Comment: I am currently using sql db trigger for auditing, like to keep track of user and its activity... but i do not know is it recommended method.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this really depends on personal preference and the application at hand.

For error logging, I use [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

For application logging, [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is very popular.

Microsoft's [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc467894.aspx) has a lot of these options built into it.

Comment: thanks for you answer but what i need your recomendation on auditing procedure . which one is best?